# VBA Using Access To Append Records from One Excel Sheet To Another

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access DB where I'm trying to copy several worksheets in a single folder into a master excel file

I first build an array of file locations called `filedetails` for the workbooks and then open each one and paste the contents into the master file. Because i don't want the files pasting over each other. The starting location on the master workbook will always be an offset of 1 from the previous pasting location. All the workbooks are in the same working directory so the code is set up to stop the Main workbook being copied into itself

The code fails at `xlSht2.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select` with the error message

> Run-Time error '424' Object Required

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'## Open Working File
Set xlBook_A = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strWF)
Set xlSht = xlBook_A.Worksheets(1)

' Open Each Sheet and Copy it into the Workbook (Except Worksheet into itself)
For intRecord = 1 To UBound(filedetails)
If (filedetails(1, intRecord)) <> strWF Then
    Set xlBook_B = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filedetails(1, intRecord))
    Set xlSht2 = xlBook_B.Worksheets(1)

    ' After the rows have been pasted, a new starting point not "A2" will need to be set
    ' This offset will be done after each copy and paste giving an Append operation to MS Excel
    ' So Sheet A wont overwrite Sheet B
    xlSht2.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    xlSht2.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    xlSht2.Selection.Copy Destination:=xlSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

End If

Next intRecord
```

Can anyone see where im going wrong?

Comment: I'm not so sure what Selection would point to

Comment: This is basically where the script is selecting from A2 and then shift+ctrl and left arrow and then down arrow to highlight all the records that need to be copied. If you imagine that the excel sheet has 3 columns and 150 rows per column

Comment: I'm not sure `Selection` would point to some `xlSht2` cell. Maybe it's pointing to the hosting application (MSAccess?) current selection. Better go with full range qualification such as `xlSht2.Range(xlSht2.range("A1"), xlSht2.range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=xlSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, Remove the 3 lines before Endif and include this

```
xlSht2.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
if xlSht.Range("F1").End(xlDown).row=Rows.Count
    xlSht2.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy xlSht.Range("F1")
Else    
    xlSht2.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy xlSht.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Endif
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses, however it seems im running out of memory when i use the code...This must have something to do with the `Copy xlSht.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)` As in my test files there is at most 100*3 columns and the master file is completely empty

Comment: is master file is the target?

Comment: you must be sure that there's at least one non empty cell in column "F" after cell "F1", otherwise `xlSht.Range("F1").End(xlDown)` would get the cell in the last row and `.Offset(1, 0)` would try to reach one row more down which doesn't exist!. Also check for `Selection` actual meaning

Comment: if your master file is empty then it should be xlSht2.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy xlSht.Range("F1")

Comment: you need to check the row count of selection with target whether its between the rows

Comment: see the edit in my code. Please mark as solution if its useful to you

Comment: Hi @Karthick Im still getting the memory resources issue. The `master` file will start out blank with only the headers. So `A1:D1` will have headers but nothing else. The sheets being imported will have the same headers but data up to a couple of hundred rows

Comment: @JohnSmith, so you are now out of the error "Run-Time error '424' Object Required"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `Select` areas prior to copying. The example below should work for your situation.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim xlShtMaster As Worksheet
    Dim xlSht2 As Worksheet
    xlSht2.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=xlShtMaster.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```